# Multi-Channel Audio HTML5 with mouseover

Tags: html, audio

I'm using the brilliant info on stories in flight to generate sound on mouseover events, its part of a project on digital writing. The draft I have currently keeps stopping sound, or in Chrome showing the 'Aw, Snap' page. The page is available at http://www.nathan-walker.co.uk/sounding

I've also upped the channels to 300 (which is potentially what i need). The other problem   is I guess because i'm using WAV files and they're rather large! If someone could suggest alternatives or know some kind of workaround that would be great!

```
<audio id="multiaudio1" src="audio/flute_c_long_01.wav" preload="auto"></audio>    
<audio id="multiaudio2" src="audio/piano_chord.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="multiaudio3" src="audio/synth_vox.wav" preload="auto"></audio>    
<audio id="multiaudio4" src="audio/shimmer.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="multiaudio5" src="audio/sweep.wav" preload="auto"></audio>

<a href="javascript:play_multi_sound('multiaudio1');">Flute</a><br />
<a href="javascript:play_multi_sound('multiaudio2');">Piano Chord</a><br />
<a href="javascript:play_multi_sound('multiaudio3');">Synth Vox</a><br />
<a href="javascript:play_multi_sound('multiaudio4');">Shimmer</a><br />
<a href="javascript:play_multi_sound('multiaudio5');">Sweep</a><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
var channel_max = 10;                                       // number of channels
audiochannels = new Array();
for (a=0;a<channel_max;a++) {                                   // prepare the channels
    audiochannels[a] = new Array();
    audiochannels[a]['channel'] = new Audio();                      // create a new audio object
    audiochannels[a]['finished'] = -1;                          // expected end time for this channel
}
function play_multi_sound(s) {
    for (a=0;a<audiochannels.length;a++) {
        thistime = new Date();
        if (audiochannels[a]['finished'] < thistime.getTime()) {            // is this channel finished?
            audiochannels[a]['finished'] = thistime.getTime() + document.getElementById(s).duration*1000;
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].src = document.getElementById(s).src;
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].load();
            audiochannels[a]['channel'].play();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 300 channels is very extreme for a web browser. You can crash it easily. Chrome set a lot of virtual memory paging (about 4x as much as my 2nd largest page), and crashed soon after.

Second, why use wavs? I would convert them into a compressed format and have the browser's player decompress it on the fly so you can save space.

Finally, instead of using the `<audio>` element (which is only designed for simple media playback), I would consider using the Web Audio API if possible - which it certainly is in the current Chrome and Safari versions. It's more performance modeled than the `<audio>` tag, which would be what you would be looking for in an experiment like this. It's not TERRIBLY difficult to use, as long as you follow the instructions. Here's a link to a tutorial.: http://creativejs.com/resources/web-audio-api-getting-started/

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great. How do I have the browser decompress on the fly? I'll have a look at the API and see what I can do, this is an experiment so thanks for advice. N

Comment: The browser will just decode it on its own, no need to worry. It streams if I'm not mistaken, so memory will be less intense. Give it a go!

Comment: No IE support for Web Audio API?